# s3cmd doesn't work with logrotate?

Tags: s3cmd

I imagine this is an issue with permissions, but I can't identify it.

When you install s3cmd you have to configure it by running `s3cmd --configure`, which creates a config file at `~/.s3cfg`. I've done this for user `ubuntu`. I can correctly `put` and `get` files using s3cmd. However, when it's called from logrotate it doesn't work for whatever reason. The problem is I don't even know where logrotate error messages are being logged to. When I manually run logrotate, it does work though!

How should I go about this? Where do I look to find the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I believe `logrotate` was called by system as `root`, so `s3cmd` was called by `s3cmd` too and expect settings in `/root/.s3cfg`. If you manually run logrotate as `ubuntu` then `s3cmd` was called as `ubuntu`, so `s3cmd` expect settings in `/root/.s3cfg`.